# Traceback error when using search_engine_parser

Tags: python, csv, search

I am writing a simple script to search google using the search engine parser it was working fine until yesterday.

All search queries are stored in `test.csv` file

```
from search_engine_parser.core.engines.google import Search as GoogleSearch
import csv
with open('/Users/John/Desktop/test.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header != None:
        for row in csv_reader:
            gsearch = GoogleSearch()
            gresults = gsearch.search(row)
            print(gresults["titles"][0])
```

getting the error below:

```
"/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/venv/bin/python" "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/search_parser2.py"
Samsung Galaxy J7 - Full phone specifications - GSMArena.com
Search for samsung sm-n920c - GSMArena.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/search_engine_parser/core/base.py", line 240, in get_results
    search_results = self.parse_result(results, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/search_engine_parser/core/base.py", line 151, in parse_result
    rdict = self.parse_single_result(each, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/search_engine_parser/core/engines/google.py", line 74, in parse_single_result
    title = r_elem.find('div', class_='BNeawe').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/search_parser2.py", line 10, in <module>
    gresults = gsearch.search(row)
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/search_engine_parser/core/base.py", line 270, in search
    return self.get_results(soup, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/John/Documents/python scripts/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/search_engine_parser/core/base.py", line 244, in get_results
    "The returned results could not be parsed. This might be due to site updates or "
search_engine_parser.core.exceptions.NoResultsOrTrafficError: The returned results could not be parsed. This might be due to site updates or server errors. Drop an issue at https://github.com/bisoncorps/search-engine-parser if this persists

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: is there more to the traceback? it seems incomplete.

Comment: here is the complete error message

Comment: Did you ever solve this?